# Automated webscraping with Python (no class/id)

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Currently I'm working on my first Python project. 
I am trying to build a simple program to automate webscraping from the site http://socialblade.com
The idea is to have a list with youtube users (excel, csv, ...) and feed this into a python script. Python would then scrape the users page and generate a csv file with most recent number of daily views or subscribers.

I have followed some tutorials on BS4, requests, ... but am getting stucked. 
It seems like on socialblade there are no class / id tags for the div's I want to scrape.

ex. This is the code for one of the items I would like to collect.

```
<div style="width: 140px; float: left;">16,518
</div>
```

Besides this I'm also not sure how to feed the links to different users in the Python program. 
Currently we have a file with a list of users (rows). One of the columns is the link to their Youtube account.

Very basic this is what I'm trying to do:

FOR user 1 to n
1) Read link from excel file for user
2) Scrape 'number of views' and 'number of subscriptions' from the socialblade page
3) write this data in an csv/excel file

Hope this is somewhat understandable :)

Thanks a lot and looking forward to progress my Python skills!

Kind regards and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understand this right, first of all you have to have the list of users in the Excel file, I don`t have one so in my case I get top 25 using this code and save it into xlsx file:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests


def get_number_of_views_and_subscriptions(socialblade_url="https://socialblade.com/youtube/"):
    """Function returns account names, account urls, number of subscribers and number of views
     from socialblade web-site using requests and xpath"""

    request = requests.get(socialblade_url)
    tree = fromstring(request.content)

    account_names = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[3]/a/text()")
    account_urls = ["https://socialblade.com" + _ for _ in tree.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[3]/a/@href")]
    subscribers = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[5]/text()")
    views = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[6]/text()")

    data = zip(account_names, account_urls, subscribers, views)

    return data


def writing_to_excel(file_path="users_data.xlsx", data=get_number_of_views_and_subscriptions()):
    """Function writes data of type ["account names", "account urls", "number of subscribers", "number of views"]
    to an xlsx file"""

    workbook = Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.create_sheet("Socialblade", 0)
    worksheet.append(["account names", "account urls", "number of subscribers", "number of views"])

    for item in data:
        worksheet.append(item)

    workbook.save(file_path)
```

Next thing is to get links and scrape information, I would do this using this code:

```
def get_excel_user_links(file_path="users_data.xlsx"):
    """Functions returns all values of the first row of Excel file"""

    workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
    worksheet = workbook.active  # or workbook.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

    values = [row[1].value for row in worksheet.iter_rows() if row[1].value != "account urls"]
    return values

def scrape_and_save_to_excel(file_path="scraped_data.xlsx", user_links=get_excel_user_links()):
    """Function scrapes users data and saves it to xlsx"""

    data = [["user link", "number of views", "number of subscribers"]]

    for user_link in user_links:
        request = requests.get(user_link)
        tree = fromstring(request.content)

        number_of_views = tree.xpath('//*[@id="YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock"]/div[4]/span[2]/text()')[0]
        number_of_subscribers = tree.xpath('//*[@id="YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock"]/div[3]/span[2]/text()')[0]

        data.append([user_link, number_of_views, number_of_subscribers])

    workbook = Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.create_sheet("Socialblade", 0)
    for item in data:
        worksheet.append(item)

    workbook.save(file_path)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response! 

As I am trying to work my way through the code, I was wondering if the excel file should be in the same directory? 

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, I have to save this code as an .py file and then run in cmd right? :)
This seems to not generate an excel file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, this is functions, to run them you have to add such line like "get_number_of_views_and_subscriptions()" in the end of the code. And yes you have to add this to .py file and run it with python. But it is better to install some IDLE to work with python.

Comment: Another question :) 
How did you identify which 'divs' to scrape? 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there is no id for div you can use index, for example for fifth div in html tree the xpath is "//div[5]" and so on. Try to learn xpath.